# Обработка 2-х ссылок

Tags: javascript, html, href

Как можно с помощью JS (или чего-то другого) реализовать 2 действия при клике на одну ссылку. К примеру, есть ссылка:

```
 <a href="/karta/city/50">Москва</a>
```

При клике на эту ссылку изменяется город на сайте, но страница остается прежней (т.е. нет перехода на /karta/city/50). Как можно реализовать, чтобы при клике на эту ссылку, был переход на URL к примеру

```
/karta/categoriya/
```

При этом обязательно должна быть обработка ссылки */karta/city/50* (т.к. идет смена города).

В общем получается как-бы 2 URL чтобы обрабатывались при клике, но открывался только один по ссылке */karta/categoriya/* и при этом произошла смена города.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть вариант, реализации через AJAX, при нажатии на ссылку отправка запроса по URL, который прописан в href, по возвращению результата ajax переход на новый адрес через window.location

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ. Можете пожалуйста привести пример как это сделать? Плохо разбираюсь в этом. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, конечно. Только нужно подключить на сайте jQuery. Что-то в этом роде http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwRXdd.

Comment: Кстати как я понял, при переходе на сайт у вас на карте происходят изменения, если бы вы уточнили каким образом записывается город (cookie, session) можно было бы сделать более правильно

Comment: Как я понимаю берет из session — cmsUser::sessionSet('maps-city', $city);

Comment: Не обязательно, здесь идет вызов метода класса cmsUser. Перейдите по ссылке и проверьте какие записи есть в cookie, возможно так будет проще.

Comment: Ваш вариант работает отлично. Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли вариант как-то в 1 ссылку это разместить? Просто ссылок много, как и категорий и при размещении на разных страницах придется добавлять доп.код, который вы показали.

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос.

Comment: Простите, сам не понял что написал:-) Смотрите ссылок с городами очень много (/karta/city/50, /karta/city/51, /karta/city/52) так же как и много категорий на которую нужно отправить пользователя. Можно ли как-то разместить в ссылке код jQuery?. Просто так придется на каждой странице где размещена ссылка (или несколько ссылок), добавлять разный код jQuery (с разными ссылками внутри кода). В общем сделать что-то наподобие  <a href="link..." onclick="...."

Comment: Можно как вариант, при нажатии на кнопку вызывать функцию, а в атрибуты типа data-* прописать данные необходимые для перехода.

Comment: Всю голову поломал уже, не выходит ничего. Lam, скажите пожалуйста, а возможно ли как-то передавать из ссылки, 2 значения URL'a в код, который вы написали http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwRXdd? Т.е. чтобы я разместил 1  jQuery код на странице, в котором ajax({url:... и document.location.href... брались непосредственно из самой ссылки?

Comment: Вопрос решен. Прямой ссылкой на категорию и получением ID из ссылки, где ID это ID города. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score -2):

Создаешь событие при клике на 1 ссылку и в ней с помощью  `$('#id').click()` переходишь по другой

Comment: Спасибо. Если не затруднит, можете показать готовый пример.